# Gnome 3 UI menus are duplicated

Tags: debian, xorg, gnome3, gui, display-manager

Just upgraded from Debian "Squeezy" to "Wheezy". When I logged in the menus were fancier as I expected with *Gnome Display Manager 3*.

**However the issue that occurred was the duplicate UI-elements**. The UI-elements such as "Applications", "Places", the Clock and so forth had two instances each.

**What I've tried so far:**

- Though it had something to do with me having a two monitor setup so I
  ran `nvidia-settings` and reconfigured `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`.

  However as I rebooted the UI elements had increased and now there
  were three instances. I think this number increases with each reboot...
- Tried to manually rewrite the `xorg.conf` by saving in my home folder
  and then pushing it into `/etc/X11/xorg.conf
- Renaming `~/.gnome2` to `~/gnome2_backup`

Why do I get the duplicate menus and is there a way to remove them/make them not appear after each reboot?

**My xorg.conf file:**

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 304.88  (pbuilder@cake)  Wed Apr  3 08:58:25 UTC 2013

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" 1920 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "1"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "DELL S2740L"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Samsung SMBX2440"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 81.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GT 430"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
    Screen          0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GT 430"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
    Screen          1
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DFP: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "CRT-1"
    Option         "metamodes" "CRT: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Extensions"
    Option         "Composite" "Disable"
EndSection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was some spooky settings or cached data from Gnome 2 that was messing with the interface. I saved the important files to an external drive and emptied the home folder, (including .*-files).